# Knex - updating rows where value from select

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, knex.js

I am using an sqlite3 DB and have these two tables.

**List**:

- ID
- OriginID

**Attributes**:

- ID
- ListID
- OriginList

Attributes.OriginList == List.OriginID

I need to update rows in Attributes to match the current List.ID. I am using Knex and my current raw query looks like this:

```
UPDATE Attributes 
SET ListID = (SELECT ID 
              FROM List 
              WHERE OriginID = Attributes.OriginList)
```

I just started with DBs and have been trying to come up with ways to do this without raw, but haven't been successful. Is there such a way?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should create the RAW query mentioned in OP:

```
knex('Attributes').update({ 
  ListID: knex('List').select('ID').where('OriginID', knex.raw('??', ['Attributes.OriginList']))
})
```